# how to do image auto slide

Tags: jquery, image

Three functionalities  i want

1. on click next, image should slide to the next one
2. on click prev, image should slide to previous one
3. within  5 sec image should auto slide

I have found this plugin from somewhere this 
has all the functionalities and working properly as i want but how to do image auto slide in this there is commented code for auto slide but uncommenting it doesn,t work for me
i dont want to change plugin  so plz do modification in only

```
(function (window) {

        Ladduslider = function () {

            //global vars
            this.curItem = 0;
            this.w = 652;
            this.h = 200;
            this.dur = 1000;
            this.wait = 3000;
            this.tot = 0;
            this.f = '';
            this.anim = false;


            //fadein fadeout functions
            this.init = function (dc, chld, f) {

                this.f = "." + f;

                if (dc === '') return;

                var child = $('.' + chld);
                //("#mc .ff")
                var numofdivs = $('#' + dc + ' .' + chld).length;
                var w = this.w;

                child.each(function (i) {
                    $(this).addClass(f + parseInt(i + 1));

                    //next piece of code for slide only
                    $(this).css({
                        "left": w + "px",
                        "display": "block"
                    });
                    //console.log(w);
                });
                this.tot = numofdivs;

                //display first
                this.curItem = 1;
                //$(".f" + curItem).css("display","block"); //for fade
                $("." + f + this.curItem).css("left", 0); //for slide

                //start anim
                //doWait();
            }

            this.doWait = function () {
                //setTimeout(doFade,wait); //for fadein and out
                setTimeout(this.doSlide, this.wait); //for slide
            }

            this.doFade = function () {
                $(this.f + this.curItem).fadeTo(dur, 0);
                this.curItem++;
                if (this.curItem > this.tot) this.curItem = 1;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).fadeTo(this.dur, 1, function () {
                    this.doWait();
                });
            }

            //slide
            this.doSlide = function () {
                if (this.anim) return;
                this.anim = true;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).animate({
                    left: "-=" + this.w
                }, this.dur);
                this.curItem++;
                if (this.curItem > this.tot) this.curItem = 1;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).css("left", this.w);
                var that = this;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).animate({
                    left: "-=" + this.w
                }, this.dur, function () {
                    //doWait(); //un-comment this for auto slide
                    that.anim = false;
                });
            }

            this.doSlideR = function () {
                if (this.anim) return;
                this.anim = true;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).animate({
                    left: "+=" + this.w
                }, this.dur);
                this.curItem -= 1;
                if (this.curItem < 1) this.curItem = this.tot;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).css("left", -this.w);
                var that = this;
                $(this.f + this.curItem).animate({
                    left: "+=" + this.w
                }, this.dur, function () {
                    //doWait();
                    that.anim = false;
                });
            }
        }

        if (!window.Ladduslider) window.Ladduslider = Ladduslider();
    })(window);


    $(document).ready(function () {
        ls = new Ladduslider();
        ls.init("mc", "ff", "q");
        $(".prev").bind("click", function () {
            ls.doSlideR();
        });
        $(".next").bind("click", function () {
            ls.doSlide();
        });

        ls1 = new Ladduslider();
        ls1.init("mc1", "ff1", "q1");
        $(".prev1").bind("click", function () {
            ls1.doSlideR();
        });
        $(".next1").bind("click", function () {
            ls1.doSlide();
        });

        ls2 = new Ladduslider();
        ls2.init("mc2", "ff2", "q2");
        $(".prev2").bind("click", function () {
            ls2.doSlideR();
        });
        $(".next2").bind("click", function () {
            ls2.doSlide();
        });

    });
```

here is the html code:
i have three div but only one needs the auto slide animation so providing only on div

```
<div>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="280" width="710" style="margin-left:-22px;">
  <tr><td><div class="prev2"><img src="images/Shape-5-copy12.png" /></div></td>
      <td align="left" width="640"><div class="mc2" id="mc2"><div class="ff2" id="ff2"><div class="minH"><img src="images/01.jpg" /></div></div>
                                   <div class="ff2" id="ff2"><div class="minH"><img src="images/02.jpg" /></div></div>
                                   <div class="ff2" id="ff2"><div class="minH"><img src="images/03.png" /></div></div>                    
                                   <div class="ff2" id="ff2"><div class="minH"><img src="images/04.jpg" /></div></div></div></td>
      <td><div class="next2"><img src="images/Shape-5-copy1.png" class="imgscroller" /></div></td></tr>
  </table></div>
```

Comment: post ur HTMl too, good if u provide http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: i have given you the div in which i need the auto slide

Comment: Please edit your question to post your html, not posting as comment. Even you, cannot understand your comment right now

Comment: Maybe you can post where do you get this plugin as well.